# Printing data Python

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following data

```
id        x        y     name
312       33.76    55.2   aaa
312       33.76    55.2   bbb
443       66.33    11.5   ccc
686       44.55           ddd
222                44.6   eee
423       88.3     23.6   fff
```

I had make this

```
popularity = dict(Counter(data['id']))
print "id\tpopularity"

for k, v in popularity.items():
    print '{0:.0f}\t{1}'.format(k,v)
```

to find out the popularity

and I had find out the unique id using this code

```
 uni_id = np.unique(data['id'])
```

Now I want to print out the unique id with x and y , also the popularity but not with name and need to ignore the column without x or y

How can I combine this code together ? Thanks !

Comment: I guess the code you posted does not print the table you gave first? What does it print? Does `data` have the keys `'x'` and `'y'`?

Comment: it will print out 2 column left is id ,right is popularity

Comment: Where do you get `'x'`, `'y'` and `'name'` from?

Comment: a csv file , store and read in "data"